# Adding and object to a list inside a while loop

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to loop a list and that list have 4 arrays inside and each array have 7 values

I am looping the list and then when I get an array from the list, since I know how many values have the array I assign each array index like this: `personObject.setName(String.valueOf(myArray[0])` and then at the end of the while loop I add to a list of Persons the personObject like this: listOfPersons.add(personObject).

My problem is that my list only gets populate with the same object and I know that the 4 arrays inside the list that I'm looping have different values, here is my code:

```
ArrayList<Object> objectList= null;
objectList= _serviceVariable.getObjects(); <--- this works it returns a list with 4 arrays all with diferent values

Person myPerson = new Person();
List<Person> personsList = new List<Person>; 

Iterator<Object> itr = objectList.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext())
        {
Object[] innerObj = (Object[]) itr.next();

myPerson.setName(String.valueOf(innerObj [0])
myPerson.setLastName(String.valueOf(innerObj [1])
myPerson.setNickName(String.valueOf(innerObj [2])

personsList.add(myPerson); 
}
```

when I print my persons list is full of persons with the same name, lastName and nick name, is a list full of the same objects with the same values.

Comment: also try using ArrayList<String[]> objectList, use templating, dont cast it

Comment: in what part should i use that friend?

Comment: ArrayList<Object> instead of using that, and casting it later, use proper type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you are adding a `Person` you want to add a **different** person right?

Therefore, you should create a **`new`** `Person` object inside your loop every time.
Not create only one outside of the loop whose data you just keep changing.

```
// NOT HERE Person myPerson = new Person();
// ...

while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Object[] innerObj = (Object[]) itr.next();

    Person myPerson = new Person(); // HERE you create a new Person        
    myPerson.setName(String.valueOf(myArray[0]);
    myPerson.setLastName(String.valueOf(myArray[1]);
    myPerson.setNickName(String.valueOf(myArray[2]);

    personsList.add(myPerson); // add the new person to the list
}
```

Comment: are you sure, the iterator iterates fine since i get a list with the same amount of values.

And if i do that i wouldnt be able to set my object attributes

Answer (score 2):

You are adding (and modifying) the same object instance to the loop multiple times because you only create one `Person` instance, move that into the loop.

```
// Person myPerson = new Person();
// ...
while(itr.hasNext()) {
  Person myPerson = new Person(); // <-- HERE!
  Object[] innerObj = (Object[]) itr.next();
  myPerson.setName(String.valueOf(myArray[0])
  myPerson.setLastName(String.valueOf(myArray[1])
  myPerson.setNickName(String.valueOf(myArray[2])
  personsList.add(myPerson); 
}
```

And you will create multiple instances and add them to your loop.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as the OP now, but I still don't know why it keeps adding the same object. I'm changing its values with setters so shouldn't it add the same object with new properties? Or is this just by design in Java/OOP?

Comment: @Denny If you don't use `new`, you don't instantiate a new reference. Thus, each `Object` is actually the same `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code, it looks to me .
You are not reading data from related array, which is `innerObj`.
replace of `myArray[0]`, it should be **innerObj[0]** and
 `Person p = new Person()` inside loop to set new value otherwise it will get override.

```
while(itr.hasNext()) {
  Person p= new Person(); // <-- HERE!
  Object[] innerObj = (Object[]) itr.next();
  p.setName(String.valueOf(innerObj [0])
  p.setLastName(String.valueOf(innerObj [1])
  p.setNickName(String.valueOf(innerObj [2])
  personsList.add(p); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foobar {
    class Person {
        String name;

        Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    class SpecialPerson extends Person {
        SpecialPerson(String name) {
            super(name);
        }
    }

    public void myFoobar() {
        List<List<Person>> ListOfPersonsList = new ArrayList<List<Person>>();

        List<Person> persons1 = new ArrayList<Person>();
        persons1.add(new Person("Foo"));

        List<Person> persons2 = new ArrayList<Person>();
        persons2.add(new Person("Bar"));

        ListOfPersonsList.add(persons1);
        ListOfPersonsList.add(persons2);

        List<SpecialPerson> specials = new ArrayList<SpecialPerson>();

        for (List<Person> persons : objectList) {
            for (Person person : persons) {
                specials.add(new SpecialPerson(person.name));
            }

        }

        for (SpecialPerson special : specials) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + special.name);
        }

    }

}
```